# Why does Google Chrome fail to interact with an element sometimes

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im learning selenium and am new to this.
Im trying to generate an automated script to reach out to the gmail registration page and then fill in all the details.
Here's what i want to do in brief:
1.Launch google chrome with baseurl as "www.google.com"
2.Click on the gmail link (top right corner beside "Images")
3.On the Gmail login page, click on "More options"
4.Click on "Create Account"
5.Type in test data into the fields

The problem that im encountering is that, sometimes the Create Account link is clicked successfully and sometimes it is not.

Im using selenium with java.

Here's the code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\TESTING\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    String baseUrl = "http:\\www.google.co.in";
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gbw\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"view_container\"]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div")).click();

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("SIGNUP")));
    driver.findElement(By.className("z80M1")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.findElement(By.id("FirstName")).sendKeys("abcd");
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.close();
```

Sometimes the Create Account link is clicked successfully and sometimes it is not.
Encountering this error sometimes:

Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"FirstName"}

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Also, please do let me know if im doing something incorrectly.

Comment: Try putting little pauses in your code using `Thread.sleep()` to allow the document to finish rendering/loading.

Comment: @Bohemian: Thank a lot..
after using the thread.sleep() the script is working perfectly each and every time i run it.

Comment: But what i fail to understand is that, why didnt the explicit and implicit wait function correctly.
i used thread.sleep(1000) (just a 1 second pause) and everything works fine everytime is run the script.
but when i use explicit and implicit wait, keeping the wait time to even 9 seconds or more, still the same problem is encountered, i.e. sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt.
Any possible reason for this??

Comment: see my answer for why

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing explicit/implicit wait time. Current wait is 2 seconds and it seems that element is not loading in 2 seconds time limit

Comment: tried increasing the wait time for both, implicit and explicit waits to 9 seconds or more, still the same problem persists.
however, as suggested by @bohemian: used thread.sleep() for 1 sec pause and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

*What* Selenium does (at least the *intention*) is great. *How* it does it is, has always been, and is likely to always be, a little flakey.

Generally speaking, the API works, but not properly. Every time I have used it, I have found that timing/events etc don't work properly. That is, stuff isn't "done" when Selenium thinks it is.

Tips:

- **never** trust Selenium to know what is going on
- **always** code your own pauses between actions

Typically, I sleep 1 second *after* the notification from Selenium that the page has loaded. Sometimes I need an even greater pause.

Although this will slow down your tests, it's generally not a big deal because behavioural test suites usually take quite a while (hours) to complete anyway. And it's better to avoid false negatives.